# How create a new deep copy (clone) of a List<T>?

Tags: c#, list, clone, deep-copy

In the following piece of code,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace clone_test_01
{

    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {

        public class Book
        {
            public string title = "";

            public Book(string title)
            {
                this.title = title;
            }
        }


        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            List<Book> books_1 = new List<Book>();
            books_1.Add(  new Book("One")  );
            books_1.Add(  new Book("Two")  );
            books_1.Add(  new Book("Three")  );
            books_1.Add(  new Book("Four")  );

            List<Book> books_2 = new List<Book>(books_1);

            books_2[0].title = "Five";
            books_2[1].title = "Six";

            textBox1.Text = books_1[0].title;
            textBox2.Text = books_1[1].title;
        }
    }

}
```

I use a `Book` object type to create a `List<T>` and I populate it with a few items giving them a unique title (from 'one' to 'five').

Then I create `List<Book> books_2 = new List<Book>(books_1)`.

From this point, I know it's a clone of the list object, BUT the book objects from `book_2` are still a reference from the book objects in `books_1`. It's proven by making changes on the two first elements of `books_2`, and then checking those same elements of `book_1` in a `TextBox`.

`books_1[0].title and books_2[1].title` have indeed been changed to the new values of `books_2[0].title and books_2[1].title`.

**NOW THE QUESTION**

How do we create a new hard copy of a `List<T>`? The idea is that `books_1` and `books_2` become completely independent of each other.

I'm disappointed Microsoft didn't offer a neat, fast and easy solution like Ruby are doing with the `clone()` method.

What would be really awesome from helpers is to use my code and alter it with a workable solution so it can be compiled and work. I think it will truly help newbies trying to understand offered solutions for this issue.

EDIT: Note that the `Book` class could be more complex and have more properties. I tried to keep things simple.

Comment: Something like `CopyTo`?

Comment: This type of copying is normally called [deep copy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_copy#Deep_copy). If you feel "hard copy" is something different that you actually need in your case - please undo my edit and add your definition of the term.

Comment: A [hard copy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_copy) means that you print it out onto a physical sheet of paper.

Comment: Please check out other related questions about deep-copy asked before - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23+deep-copy?sort=faq&pagesize=50

Comment: I meant deep-copy indeed, sorry I'm still a newbies.

Comment: Personally I like to use a short serialisation & deserialisation routine that achieves the deep copy - de/serialisation is slow(ish), but this works no matter how many properties the object has. Unfortunately I'm on holiday so I can't just post the code.

Comment: Deep-copy each element of the list. It depends on the contents of your list.

Comment: IMO deep cloning is inherently not neat.

Comment: just create a new list with linq

Answer (score 143, accepted):

You need to create new `Book` objects then put those in a new `List`:

```
List<Book> books_2 = books_1.Select(book => new Book(book.title)).ToList();
```

Update: Slightly simpler... `List<T>` has a method called [`ConvertAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73fe8cwf.aspx) that returns a new list:

```
List<Book> books_2 = books_1.ConvertAll(book => new Book(book.title));
```

Comment: What if the Book object was more complex and had thousands of other properties?

Comment: +1, @TheScholar - than you either create copy contructor or implement some other way to create Deep-copy of an object.

Comment: @TheScholar: Then it would be a badly designed class. Thousands of properties... are you serious?

Comment: @MarkByers it was a figure of speeach of course. My example provide a single property for the sake of keeping the example simple and easy to read.

Comment: The new question can be simplified to "how do I copy a single object in C#?"

Comment: Thanks a lot guys for the efforts. I realize that copying data or attempting to swap them is a bit more complicated than I expected.

Comment: Why is the `ToList()` not enough? Why do you need the `Select` statement too?

Comment: @RoberF. `ToList()` is not enough because the OP asked for a deep copy. The `ToList()` alone would be a shallow copy. The `Select` copy not only the list, but the objects inside it.

Comment: this is too expensive

Comment: @Vidyesh - Its too expensive compared to what? The spec is to create a list *with new objects in it*.  The only way to do that, is to *create new objects*. If you *don't* need "new objects", then you don't need "deep copy" - you simply do `.ToList()`. But that isn't the subject of this Q&A.

Answer (score 47):

Create a generic `ICloneable<T>` interface which you implement in your `Book` class so that the class knows how to create a copy of itself.

```
public interface ICloneable<T>
{
    T Clone();
}

public class Book : ICloneable<Book>
{
    public Book Clone()
    {
        return new Book { /* set properties */ };
    }
}
```

You can then use either the linq or `ConvertAll` methods that Mark mentioned.

```
List<Book> books_2 = books_1.Select(book => book.Clone()).ToList();
```

or

```
List<Book> books_2 = books_1.ConvertAll(book => book.Clone());
```

Answer (score 24):

> I'm disappointed Microsoft didn't offer a neat, fast and easy solution like Ruby are doing with the `clone()` method.

Except that does *not* create a deep copy, it creates a shallow copy.

With deep copying, you have to be always careful, what exactly do you want to copy. Some examples of possible issues are:

1. Cycle in the object graph. For example, `Book` has an `Author` and `Author` has a list of his `Book`s.
2. Reference to some external object. For example, an object could contain open `Stream` that writes to a file.
3. Events. If an object contains an event, pretty much anyone could be subscribed to it. This can get especially problematic if the subscriber is something like a GUI `Window`.

Now, there are basically two ways how to clone something:

1. Implement a `Clone()` method in each class that you need cloned. (There is also `ICloneable` interface, but you should *not* use that; using a custom `ICloneable<T>` interface as Trevor suggested is okay.) If you know that all you need is to create a shallow copy of each field of this class, you could use [`MemberwiseClone()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone.aspx) to implement it. As an alternative, you could create a “copy constructor”: `public Book(Book original)`.
2. Use serialization to serialize your objects into a `MemoryStream` and then deserialize them back. This requires you to mark each class as `[Serializable]` and it can also be configured what exactly (and how) should be serialized. But this is more of a “quick and dirty” solution, and will most likely also be less performant.

Comment: Why should you not use the default ICloneable interface but instead use a custom generic one?

Comment: I would also like to know why I should not use ICloneable?

Comment: @d0rf47 [The documentation explains it:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icloneable) "Because callers of Clone() cannot depend on the method performing a predictable cloning operation, we recommend that ICloneable not be implemented in public APIs."

Comment: @svick I see, but lets just say for arguments sake, I could make mine perform the deep copy if i wanted to just for a small program that no one else is ever going to use right? It seems like its just not recommended since they implementation method isn't enforced and can therefor vary if returning deep vs shallow, is this a correct understanding?

Answer (score 12):

C# 9 [records](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-9#record-types) and [with expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/with-expression) can make it a little easier, especially if your type has many properties.

You can use something like:

```cs
var books2 = books1.Select(b => b with { }).ToList();
```

I did this as an **example**:

```cs
record Book
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

static void Main()
{
    List<Book> books1 = new List<Book>()
    {
        new Book { Name = "Book1.1" },
        new Book { Name = "Book1.2" },
        new Book { Name = "Book1.3" }
    };

    var books2 = books1.Select(b => b with { }).ToList();

    books2[0].Name = "Changed";
    books2[1].Name = "Changed";

    Console.WriteLine("Books1 contains:");
    foreach (var item in books1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Books2 contains:");
    foreach (var item in books2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

And the output was: (Changes made to objects in Books2 did not affect original objects in Books1)

> Books1 contains:
>
> Book { Name = Book1.1 }
>
> Book { Name = Book1.2 }
>
> Book { Name = Book1.3 }
>
> Books2 contains:
>
> Book { Name = Changed }
>
> Book { Name = Changed }
>
> Book { Name = Book1.3 }

Answer (score 11):

You can use this:

```
var newList= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Book>>(list.toJson());
```

Comment: This has some limitations, but worked wonderful for my use case straight out of the box. Saved me the headache of implementing copy methods everywhere. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Well,

If you mark all involved classes as serializable you can :

```
public static List<T> CloneList<T>(List<T> oldList)  
{  
  BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();  
  MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();  
  formatter.Serialize(stream, oldList);  
  stream.Position = 0;  
  return (List<T>)formatter.Deserialize(stream);      
}
```

Source:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5c9b4c31-850d-41c4-8ea3-fae734b348c4/copy-listsomeobject-to-clone-list?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: When everything else failed, this one helped me. I had an object type property and there was no other way which could make a copy of that property. Thanks for the snippet.

Comment: This is just works if you have easy typed properties, if you have a subclass instance eg. you should implement the iserialiable.

Answer (score 9):

```
List<Book> books_2 = new List<Book>(books_2.ToArray());
```

That should do exactly what you want. [Demonstrated here.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JG9BV0)

Comment: This works, but note that one can't just pass new List<Book>(books_2.ToArray()); to a function.  It has to be done just like it's posted and then "books_2" could be passed.

Comment: This does not work for reference types.  What you end up with is a pointer to the original.  If you update a property on one you have now changed both!

Comment: That's the cleanest solution to deep copy an array. Thanks man. You saved lot of my time.

Comment: As this does not work for reference types, why not just call `ToList()` on a list of value types, I don't see a difference.

Answer (score 2):

Since `Clone` would return an object instance of Book, that object would first need to be cast to a Book before you can call `ToList` on it.  The example above needs to be written as:

```
List<Book> books_2 = books_1.Select(book => (Book)book.Clone()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public static class Cloner
{
    public static T Clone<T>(this T item)
    {
        FieldInfo[] fis = item.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        object tempMyClass = Activator.CreateInstance(item.GetType());
        foreach (FieldInfo fi in fis)
        {
            if (fi.FieldType.Namespace != item.GetType().Namespace)
                fi.SetValue(tempMyClass, fi.GetValue(item));
            else
            {
                object obj = fi.GetValue(item);
                if (obj != null)
                    fi.SetValue(tempMyClass, obj.Clone());
            }
        }
        return (T)tempMyClass;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the Array class meets your needs, you could also use the List.ToArray method, which copies elements to a new array.

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x303t819(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: in my instance this was the easiest approach. eg: var tagsToRead = new List<string>( tagsFailed.ToArray());

Comment: Except the objects in the array are still references to the items in the original list.

Answer (score -3):

Straight forward simple way to copy any generic list :

```
List<whatever> originalCopy=new List<whatever>();//create new list
originalCopy.AddRange(original);//perform copy of original list
```

Comment: This is not a copy, rather a shadow list with references to the same items in the list. Modifying an item in List A will modify the same item in List B because they are the same.