# How to copy List without affecting first List

Tags: c#, list

I try copy a list, but when I change the second list, the first list is changed with the second list.

My model class:

```
public class urunler : ICloneable
{
public int id { get; set; }
public string icerik { get; set; }
}
```

Extensions class:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace Extensions
{
    public static class Extensions {

        public static IList<T> Clone<T>(this IList<T> SourceList) where T: ICloneable
        {
            return SourceList.Select(item => (T)item.Clone()).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

BLL class:

```
using System.Linq;
using Extensions;
public class bll
{
    public void examp
    {
        List<urunler> L1 = new List<urunler>();
        urunler U = new urunler();
        U.icerik="old";
        L1.Add(U);
        List<urunler> L2 = L1.Clone();
        L2[0].icerik="new";
        MessageBox.show(L1[0].icerik);
        MessageBox.show(L2[0].icerik);
        //
    }
}
```

Error:

```
error CS0535: `urunler' does not implement interface member `System.ICloneable.Clone()'
```

And then I try change model class:

```
public class urunler : ICloneable
{
    #region ICloneable implementation

    IList<urunler> ICloneable.Clone()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException ();
    }

    #endregion
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string icerik { get; set; }
}
```

error:

```
error CS0539: `System.ICloneable.Clone' in explicit interface declaration is not a member of interface
```

It works this time, I changed my model class

```
public class urunler : ICloneable
{
    public object Clone()         
    {             
        return this.MemberwiseClone();         
    }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string icerik { get; set; }
}
```

And changed my bll class:

```
//before:
//List<urunler> L2 = L1.Clone();
//after:
List<urunler> L2 = L1.Clone().toList();
```

Comment: You are copying references. Use clone method or CopyTo method or ctor with old list list to create an in dependent list based on an original.

Comment: Answered many times http://stackoverflow.com/a/222623/125740

Comment: Do your research please.

Comment: You have too clone the list. Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222598/how-do-i-clone-a-generic-list-in-c.

Comment: It's funny that you commented out `//or L2.AddRange(L1);` because that would've worked.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How create a new deep copy (clone) of a List<T>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14007405/how-create-a-new-deep-copy-clone-of-a-listt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can write your Extension Method for it:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IList<T> Clone<T>(this IList<T> SourceList) where T: ICloneable
    {
        return SourceList.Select(item => (T)item.Clone()).ToList();
    }
}
```

use like this:

```
List<urunler> L2 = L1.Clone();
```

Your class:

```
public class urunler : ICloneable 
{ 
public int id { get; set; } 
public string ismi { get; set; } 
public string icerik { get; set; }

 public object Clone()
    {
        return this.MemberwiseClone();
    } 

}
```

Comment: `CopyTo` copies to an array, not a `List<T>`

Comment: I try, but don't work myclass name ex:urunler `List<string> str = new List<string>().Clone() //is work,
List<urunler> urun = new List<urunler>().Clone() // is not work, expansion does not come after the dot`

Comment: put public with class

Comment: myclass is public. `public class urunler
{
 public int id { get; set; }
 public string ismi { get; set; }
 public string icerik { get; set; }
}`

Comment: add public to extensions class

Comment: See the update also you need to inherit urunler  from IClonable:``public class urunler:ICloneable``

Comment: I couldn't =)) `error CS0535: urunler does not implement interface member System.ICloneable.Clone()` I try add interface but I couldn't again :D

Comment: add this in the class:``public object Clone()
        {
            return this.MemberwiseClone();
        }``

Comment: see edited post as well, this time i tested on my system in a sample project its working

Answer (score 1):

You're not copying a list, you're making a new reference to the same list. To copy a List, try this:

```
List<urunler> L2 = new List<urunler>(L1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `ToList()` to create a copy / new list

```
var L2 = L1.ToList();
```

If you wish to create a new list, *and* create copies of the individual list-items, you will need to add a 'Clone' method to your object definition:

```
public class urunler : ICloneable
{
    public Object Clone()
    {
        return this.MemberwiseClone();
    }
}
```

Then:

```
var L2 = L1.Select(item => (urunler)item.Clone()).ToList();
```

Comment: I try but don't create new list. problem is contineu :(

Answer (score 0):

L2=L1 Here's the mistake.
L2 is referencing the same List as L1.
You need to make a new List and copy the items:

```
L2 = new List<urunler>();
L1.CopyTo(L1);
//Edit: the above is wrong
L2 = new List<urunler>(L1);
```

Comment: `CopyTo` copies to an array, not a `List<T>`

Comment: I did try, but have a error. I change `L1.CopyTo(L1.toArray());` but it's not do that I want

Comment: L2 = new List<urunler>(L1) is the correct way to go

Answer (score 0):

Your type `urunler` appears to be a `class`, hence a reference type. Can you show us the definition of the `urunler` class, please?

Therefore, even when you clone the **list** correctly, you still produce a **shallow** clone. The two distinct `List<>` instances will have references to the same instance of `urunler`.

When you do `L2 = L1;`, you don't even clone the `List<>`. You just have two references to the same `List<>`, so that goes wrong at an early stage.

When you do `L2 = new List<urunler>(L1);` or `L2 = L1.ToList();` or `L2 = new List<urunler>(); L2.AddRange(L1);`, you get the shallow copy I described. There are two distinct lists of references, but they refer to the same `urunler` instance.

Consider the cloning solution of the edited version of Dave Bish's answer.

Depending of your semantics, you could also make `urunler` an **immutable type**. Then instead of stuff like:

```
L2[0].icerik = "new";
```

you would have to do:

```
L2[0] = new urunler { icerik = "new", OtherProp = L2[0].OtherProp, };
```

etc.