# How can I make changes to some Copied list that contains reference-type objects without changing the original one

Tags: c#

I Have `List<PropertyDetails> OriginalList` which I clone it to another 
list by : `List<PropretyDetails> CopiedList = OriginalList.ToList();`

Now I pass the `CopiedList` to some method that alters it.

Myproblem is the alterations are reflected to the `OriginalList`

Comment: Can you please show your short but complete program.

Comment: You have to *Deep Copy* your objects in the list. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14007405/how-create-a-new-deep-copy-clone-of-a-listt

Comment: and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/deep-cloning-objects for deep copying an object.

Comment: @SonerGönül Thank you but it is so complicated

Comment: @Habib Thank you, do you know some way of DeepCopying that does not require the objects's class to be Serializable?

Comment: Actually this is normal because your list contains reference objects. so it just refer to them in memory. I think as @Habib said is the better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reference type is really a pointer to an object.  And because PropertyDetails is also a reference type, copying the list just gives you a new list of pointers that point to the original objects.  As Habbib pointed out, you'll have to create copies of the objects in the list, and build a new list that contains these copies.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing something like this: CopiedList[0] = OriginalList[0] and the objects are reference types, CopiedList[0] will be pointing to the same address in memory than OriginalList[0]. Thus, when you change something for CopiedList[0] you will be editing the same object in memory in OriginalList. When you are copying the objects to the CopiedList you will need to create a new instance of that object with the same values of the OriginalList. You can take a look at [ICloneable Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable.aspx) which is the standard way of doing this.  Also there are other questions related to this, like for example this one: [Deep cloning objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/deep-cloning-objects)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is clone your list to make some changes without having the original one modified, right?

Check @ajm answers in here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/222640/1435499

You can actually create a extension method to clone the list :), it shouldn't be hard.