# How to copy data from ObservableCollection with conditions?

Tags: c#, wpf

I want a copy of an ObservableCollection by filtering it with some condition. Please help me.
I treid the following code:

```
ObservableCollection<YourEntity> clonedCollection = new ObservableCollection<YourEntity>(clonedList);
```

This is ok, but need copy with condition (new object filtered from the old one). need to copy some particular data from clonedList

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How create a new deep copy (clone) of a List<T>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14007405/how-create-a-new-deep-copy-clone-of-a-listt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a linq query to filer the elements in the source collection.
A `.Where()` query does it pretty good. You can use `.Select()` or any other query too.

```
ObservableCollection<YourEntity> cloned = new ObservableCollection<YourEntity>(source.Where(e => e.IsSomeConditionFulfilled()));
```

Note that you do not clone the objects passing an `IEnumerable` to the constructor of the `ObservableCollection` - both collections `cloned` and `source` will reference the same objects. That means, if you change some `YourEntity` instance properties via the `source` collection (e. g. `source.First().SomeProperty = SomeValue`), and this object is also contained  in the `cloned` collection (e. g. `cloned.First() == source.First()`), then those changes will be reflected there.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply. ok, I can understand. But i need to clone observableCollection (with reference of cloned collection). by passing some conditions to filter the cloned object, which is to be affected in both objects.