# Wierd way C# passes in lists as arguments

Tags: c#

So i ran into this bug where C# behaves like i passed in a list by reference and not by value, like it usually does. Let me show an example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace testprogram
{
    class Program
    {
        static int x;
        static List<Coordinate> coordinates;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            x = 10;
            coordinates = new List<Coordinate>();
            coordinates.Add(new Coordinate(0, 0));
            coordinates.Add(new Coordinate(1, 1));

            testfunction(x, coordinates);
            Console.WriteLine(x);
            foreach (var objekt in coordinates)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(objekt.xpos);
                Console.WriteLine(objekt.ypos);
            }
            Console.Read();
        }

        static void testfunction(int test, List<Coordinate> objects)
        {
            test = 4;

            foreach (Coordinate obj in objects)
            {
                obj.xpos = 4;
                obj.ypos = 4;
            }
        }


    }

    class Coordinate
    {
        public int xpos;
        public int ypos;

        public Coordinate(int new_x, int new_y)
        {
            xpos = new_x;
            ypos = new_y;
        }
    }
}
```

This code outputs:

```
10 
4
4
4
4
```

But why? I expected it to be:

```
10
0
0
1
1
```

I tried to make an extra List in the Funktion and assign the value of the parameter to it but even that didn´t work. Is there some workaround for this?

Comment: Primitive types (int) are passed by value. Objects (e.g List<Coordinate>) is passed by reference... See C# 101 preface...

Comment: List is inherently a reference type, while your int is not.  Both are passed by value, but for a list that copied value is a (new) pointer, pointing to the SAME underlying list.  So the List values really are updated, whereas the int is not.

Comment: I think this is a good beginner question. I don't think minus votes are appropriate here. I vote the question +1.

Comment: In. NET, some types are always passed by reference. The List<T> class, as well as your Coordinate class, would behave this way. You'll need to look up Value Types and Reference Types to understand why.

Comment: @Biscuits - your statement is incorrect.  Types are only passed by reference is you use the `ref` or `out` keyword.  Reference types will be passed by value (i.e. the reference itself will be passed as a value, not the object that the reference is pointing to).  See the comment that I added to my answer.

Comment: @LeopardSkinPillBoxHat Apologies, that came out all wrong. Not sure how to say it simply, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expectations are wrong. The list is passed as a value. It means that variable named `objects` is a value-copy of original list variable. But the list contains references, I mean the contents of the list are references to `Coordinate` objects. So if you would try to change the list variable like `objects = new List<>()`, it wouldn't change your original list. But if you change the objects inside the list, the changes are actually applied to the original list.

```
objects[0] = new Coordinate(5, 5);
objects[0].xpos = 6;
```

Both of these examples change the original list.

If you want to have the possibility to safely change anything in the list, you have to make a deep clone of it. You can use Clone() method, but it can be tricky, because you must manually clone each object inside the list. This was already answered here:
[How create a new deep copy (clone) of a List<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14007405/how-create-a-new-deep-copy-clone-of-a-listt)

Comment: Ok that makes sense. But how can i workaround this. Maybe a way to duplicate a list and its objects or something?

Comment: If you want to have the possibility to safely change anything in the list, you have to make a deep clone of it. You can use Clone() method, but it can be tricky, because you must manually clone each object inside the list.

Comment: @AlKepp - in this particular case it should be okay, since `Coordinate` only includes value types, so a shallow clone will suffice.

Answer (score 1):

The `List<T>` argument is a reference type which is passed by value.

If you modify any items in the list within the method, these will remain changed when you leave the method.

However, if you *reassign* the reference inside the method, these changes will be lost outside the method.  If you want to pass a parameter by reference, you use the `ref` keyword:

```
static void testfunction(int test, ref List<Coordinate> objects)
{
    // This will update objects outside the testfunction method
    objects = new List<Coordinate>();
}
```

You can also use the `out` keyword, which works similar to the `ref` keyword.  The only difference is that you don't have to initialise values that are passed in as `out` parameters before you call the method, and they *must* be initialised before leaving the method.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // No need to initialise variable passed as "out" parameter
    List<Coordinate> objects;
    testfunction(test, out objects);
}

static void testfunction(int test, out List<Coordinate> objects)
{
    // Removing this line would result in a compilation error
    objects = new List<Coordinate>();
}
```

Comment: @Dispersia - You can read the difference between reference and value types [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057267/what-is-the-difference-between-a-reference-type-and-value-type-in-c).  Think of a reference like a pointer to a value stored elsewhere.  When I say a reference tpye is passed by value, it means that the "pointer" value is passed in, and if that "pointer" value is updated within the method (e.g. a new object is created, or it's pointed to another object) this change won't be seen outside the method.

Answer (score 0):

You passed a reference to the list "by value". So, if you change the reference "object" in "testfunction", then "coordinates" will not change (as a pointer). But changing the elements of "object" will affect the elements of "coordinates".