# Changes made on "copy" list are reflecting original list - c#

Tags: c#, list

I have two lists, the original one and a copied one. I made a copy of the original list, because of one reason:

I need to process/work data from the original list, but I shouldn't edit it. So I created a copy of that original list to work with. But somehow changes I do on the copied list still modifies the original.

Here is my code:

```
forPrintKitchenOrders = new List<OrderTemp>();
foreach (var itemss in forPrintKitchen)
{
  forPrintKitchenOrders.Add(itemss); // HERE I AM ADDING ITEMS TO ANOTHER LIST BECAUSE I DON'T WANT TO EDIT ORIGINAL LIST (Change quantity etc)
}

if (forPrintKitchen.Count > 0)
{

  foreach (var item in forPrintKitchenOrders.ToList())
  {
      foreach (var item2 in mainList)
      {
          if (item2.MainProductID == Convert.ToInt32(item._articleCode))
          {
              //I don't know why this is happening. I loop another list (copy of original list, because I didn't want to harm original list), and when I find certain item I am reducing quantity (-1),
              //And later I realized and saw while I was debugging, that the value of quantity in my original "forPrintKitchen" list is also edited, I don't know how changed reflected there..

              int calculate = Convert.ToInt32(item._quantity)-1; //this block is making me trouble, here I am reducing quantity and later that reflects to my forPrintKitchen list even if I am editing and looping //forPrintKitchenOrders(original's copy)
              item._quantity = calculate.ToString();
          }
      }
  }
    foreach (var items in forPrintKitchen) //THIS IS MY ORIGILAN LIST AND SHE SHOULD NOT BE EDITED WHEN I EDIT "forPrintKitchenOrders" item
    {
    //Original List
        OrdersKitchen kitchen = new OrdersKitchen();
        kitchen.ProductID = Convert.ToInt32(items._articleCode);
        kitchen.UserID = Util.User.UserID;
        kitchen.UserName = Util.User.FirstName
        kitchen.LastName = Util.User.LastName
        kitchen.BillID = bill.BillID;
        kitchen.Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(items._Quantity);
        OrdersKitchen.Add(kitchen);
    }
    foreach (var itemss in mainList)
    {

        OrdersKitchen kitchen2 = new OrdersKitchen();
        kitchen2.ProductID = Convert.ToInt32(itemss.MainProductID);
        kitchen2.UserID = User.UserID;
        kitchen2.UserName = Util.User.FirstName;
        kitchen2.LastName = Util.User.LastName;
        kitchen2.BillID = bill.BillID;
        kitchen2.Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(0); //HARDCODE ZERO
        OrdersKitchen.Add(kitchen2);
    }
 }

mainList.Clear();
//forPrintKitchenOrders.Clear();
}
```

After I saw the replies, I read @sachin's post and wrote a code similar to theirs. Is this alright? It looks like it's working right now, but I am not sure is this solution ok?

```
foreach (var itemss in forPrintKitchenOrders)
{
    forPrintKitchenOrders.Add(new OrderTemp(itemss._articleCode,itemss._name,itemss._quantity,itemss._amount));
}

public class OrderTemp
{
        public string _articleCode;
        public string _name;
        public string _quantity;
        public double _amount;

        public OrderTemp(string articleCode, string name, string quantity, double amount)
        {
            _articleCode = amount;
            _name = name;
            _quantity = quantity;
            _amount = amount;
        }
}
```

Comment: These are two lists referencing the same objects. You create a new **set** that references the same objects of the old **set**. If you change a property of an object in the first, then it is changed in the second. This is because the objects you're using are reference types and not value types.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14007405/1136211

Comment: As @user3185569 comment on the first post, you are NOT coping the object from one list to another. You are coping THE REFERENCE. Yo have to change `forPrintKitchenOrders.Add(itemss);` to`forPrintKitchenOrders.Add(itemss.Clone());`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The collection that you are referring to as '**Copy List**' is **not actually a Copy**.

The elements inside the Collection are **referring to the same Objects** as in the Original Collection.

You will have to replace your copying foreach loop with something like this:

```
foreach (var item in forPrintKitchen)
{
    forPrintKitchenOrders.Add(item.Clone()); // The clone method should return a new Instance after copying properties from item.
}
```

The `Clone` method should create `new` Instance and copy each of the properties from the instance being cloned and then return the newly created Instance.

Basically you'll have to **define a method named Clone (name doesn't matter)** in `OrderTemp` class like this:

```
public class OrderTemp
{
    /*  other members of the class */
    public OrderTemp Clone()
    {
        return new OrderTemp
        {
            property1 = this.property1;
            property2 = this.property2;
            /* and so on */
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: By following your post I will edit my question and post solution I've found, but I am not sure is it right way. so could you take a look

Comment: Could you answer me is that what I wrote in my post under EDIT section OK?

Comment: and can you give me little bit explanation why does it work acctualy? :) thanks

Comment: @Roxy'Pro The `new` operator is the Key here. When you are creating an Instance using new operator, you're creating an instance different from the original one.

Answer (score 2):

You basicaly create **shallow** copy. It means it will copy all simple types, like references and generic types, but **NOT** objects content.

As solution you need to totaly copy your objects:

```
foreach (var itemss in forPrintKitchen)
{
  forPrintKitchenOrders.Add(new OrderTemp(){ /*copy itemss here*/ });
}
```

I love to use AutoMapper for this task, but if you don't want to take framework in you project you can just implement *IClonable* on your *OrderTemp* type and all necessary nested types and call *Clone()* method.

Answer (score 0):

You made a copy of the list, but the copy still contains references to the same objects; the objects themselves are not copied.