# Shorthand for Getters and Setters?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

There's so many ways to write getters and setters that it confuses me.
Are this two doing the same thing?

```
private List<MyClass> myPrivateList;

//Method 1
public List<MyClass> MyPublicList{ get => myPrivateList;  private set { } }

//Method 2
public List<MyClass> MyPublicList=> myPrivateList;
```

And if so, does this allows me to see this propierty from another class while not allowing me to edit it?

Thank you :).

Comment: From a tiny bit of testing it looks like method 2 is defining a read only property, it won't have a private set like in method 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either way, someone will be able to edit the list, as when anyone gets `myListReference = instance.MyPublicList;`, they get a reference to `myPrivateList`.

If you want to get a shallow copy of `myPrivateList`, you would want to do `get=>new List<MyClass>(myPrivateList);`. That would allow the removal or addition of items in `myListReference` without affecting `myPrivateList`.

But even then, that is merely a shallow copy, so if the items of `myListReference` are edited, the same items will be edited in `myPrivateList`. To prevent that, you would need to do a deep copy.

Exactly how to go about that deep copy would depend on the exact nature of `MyClass` but you might learn more information from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14007405/how-create-a-new-deep-copy-clone-of-a-listt), using a class that defines a [copy constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-write-a-copy-constructor).

Comment: In case you should not be able to edit the entries of the lists see also [`ReadOnlyCollection<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.readonlycollection-1) and [`List<T>.AsReadOnly`](https://learn.microsoft.comdotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.asreadonly) .. you might rather do something like `public ReadOnlyCollection<MyClass> MyPublicList => myPrivtaeList.AsReadOnly();`

Answer (score 2):

The getters in method 1 and method 2 are equivalent. Method 1 also exposes a setter that does nothing, which is not quite the same as method 2. That would lead to confusion, because from within the declaring class it lets you write things like

```
this.MyPublicList = new List<MyClass>();
```

While that line looks like it should do something, the body of the setter is empty, so it doesn't do anything. I think what you're going for would be to just not specify the setter at all:

```
public List<MyClass> MyPublicList { get => myPrivateList; }
```

If you *do* want the setter to be usable privately, then you'd need to define the body:

```
public List<MyClass> MyPublicList { get => myPrivateList; private set => myPrivateList = value; }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
private MyType _member;
public MyType GetMember() { return _member; }
public void SetMember(MyType value) { _member = value };
```

This is the basic way to protect a private member with public getter and setter methods (a property). Regardless of how you define a property, this is the C# equivalent of what will be created in [MSIL](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/cil-or-msil-microsoft-intermediate-language-or-common-intermediate-language/). That's also why you will have the `value` keyword available in the setter. Every other method is merely syntactic sugar.

The Options are:

```
// Option 1
public MyType Member { get; set; }
// Option 2
private MyType _member;
public MyType Member 
{
   get
   {
      return _member;
   }
   set
   {
      _member = value;
   }
}
// Option 3
public MyType Member 
{
   get => _member;
   set => _member = value;
}
// Option 4
public MyType Member => _member; //Only a getter, yet even shorter.
```

What you can do, is not define a setter, this means you can't do an assignment with the property outside like `Member = new MyType()`. However, you are still able to access any methods from the outside, that in turn change the value of the underlying data-structure like in `Member.Clear()`. Like @Ruzihm pointed out in his excellent answer, you would have to do object-Copying to provide an "uninteractive" copy, that provides "full" protection of the original.