# How to copy List<MapElement> by value and not by reference?

Tags: c#, linq, uwp, uwp-maps, icloneable

I'm attempting to copy a List<Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps.MapElement> but have so far only managed to copy the reference. Can anyone offer a way to do this without creating the original MapIcon object again.

I now understand why the methods i've attempted don't work, but i can't find a way around it.

```
public void MyTestFunction(BasicGeoposition nPosition) 
{

List<MapElement> MyLandmarks = new List<MapElement>();

Geopoint nPoint = new Geopoint(nPosition, AltitudeReferenceSystem.Ellipsoid);

var needleIcon = new MapIcon    //has base class MapElement
{
    Location = nPoint,                      
    NormalizedAnchorPoint = new Windows.Foundation.Point(0.5, 0.5),                    
    ZIndex = 0,                    
    Title = "Point 1"
};
            
MyLandmarks.Add(needleIcon);

// Copy Mylandmarks by value 
// Attempt 1 - copies reference
// copyOfMapElements = new List<MapElement>();
// copyOfMapElements = MyLandmarks;
//
// Attempt 2 - copies reference

copyOfMapElements = new List<MapElement>(MyLandmarks);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use LINQ to do that:

```
copyOfMapElements = MyLandmarks.Select(l => new MapIcon{ Location = l.Location,                      
    NormalizedAnchorPoint = l.NormalizedAnchorPoint,                    
    ZIndex = l.ZIndex,                    
    Title = l.Title }).ToList();
```

**Update:**
The above solution assumes that all list elements of type `MapIcon` only, but if you need more generic solution to handle all `MapElement` derived types then you can used serialization or reflection.
Check this answer for JSON serialization: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55831822/4518630

```
copyOfMapElements = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<MapElement>>(JsonSerializer.Serialize(list));
```

Comment: Thanks but its not quite working,  i get error CS1061 on l.Location, l.NormalizedAnchorPoint and l.Title.  i.e  'MapElement' does not contain a definition for 'Location' and no accessible extension method 'Location' accepting a first argument of type 'MapElement' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).

Comment: You can either use Serialization or Reflection for deep copying all your objects of different `MapElement` or derived types

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer with only `MapIcon` items in the list:

```cs
copyOfMapElements = MyLandmarks.ConvertAll(lm => new MapIcon {
    Location = lm.Location,
    NormalizedAnchorPoint = lm.NormalizedAnchorPoint,
    ZIndex = lm.ZIndex,
    Title = lm.Title
});
```

But since `MapIcon` is derived from `MapElement` class and MyLandmarks list holds `MapElement` and not `MapIcon` which has its own set of properties you cannot use the example above (kinda weird there's no `ICloneable` interface implemented for these classes), so I'd probably check for the type of the element and create new instance accordingly.

Comment: ah yes that's the route i was just starting to think about using MapElement.GetType() == typeof(MapIcon) etc. I was hoping there would be a trick i'm just not seeing.

Comment: i should add i want MyLandmarks to hold MapElement because i want to deal with different types of MapElement not just MapIcon. Otherwise i'm sure your solution would be fine!