# Why doesn't this method produce a deep copy of the List?

Tags: c#, deep-copy

In this thread:
[How create a new deep copy (clone) of a List<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14007405/how-create-a-new-deep-copy-clone-of-a-listt)

the example of the person asking is how to create a deep copy of their List. I don't see anyone providing insight as to why it didn't work. Why did the new list behave as a reference to the old one? (Or at least it's elements).

I understand how references work in C++, and I thought the way they behave in C# is similar. But maybe I am missing something. I am still new to C#.

Here is a simplified version you can paste and run:

```
namespace OOPtest1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        public class Book
        {
            public string title = "";

            public Book(string title)
            {
                this.title = title;
            }
        }
        
       
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //InitializeComponent();

            List<Book> books_1 = new List<Book>();
            books_1.Add(new Book("One"));
            books_1.Add(new Book("Two"));
            books_1.Add(new Book("Three"));
            books_1.Add(new Book("Four"));

            List<Book> books_2 = new List<Book>(books_1);

            books_2[0].title = "Five"; // this changes the books_1 element as well
            books_2[1].title = "Six"; // this changes the books_1 element as well

        }   
    
    }
}
```

I expected this to behave like a completely different collection.

Comment: It’s a different collection of the same references

Comment: `books_1` is actually a collection of references to `Book` instances, so the `List` constructor (see the [source code](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Collections/Generic/List.cs,61)) will just copy them to the new place.

Comment: [Reference types (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types)

Comment: C# references are kind of equivalent to c++ pointers. If you copied a c++ vector of pointers you would get the exact same behavior. To avoid problems like this, use immutable objects whenever you can. C# Records make immutability easier.

Comment: You have to create a method DeepCopy in Book class, inside you create a book instance and copy the properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it seems there is some familiarity here with C++, I want to open up talking about `struct` vs `class` types. It's been a looong time, but IIRC in C++ the main difference between a `struct` and `class` is accessor defaults (`public` vs `private`). In C#, the default for both is `internal`, which is closer to `private`, but there is instead a semantic difference for `struct` (value type) vs `class` (reference type). It is *strongly suggested* to prefer using class as much as possible, and reserve `struct` for types that are both *small* and *immutable*.

I start here, because it will be helpful for understanding some of what comes next, and because you could get closer to the behavior you expected by defining the `Book` type as a `struct` instead of a `class`. But again: this is **not recommended**.

Going further, and knowing that `Book` is a reference type, C# does not make the assumption that copying the memory data of a reference type object is enough to deep copy the object. Think open streams, file handles, com/serial ports, database connections, references to other memory/objects, items that expect unique guid members, etc. If you need to be able to take deep copies, you must provide the code to do that yourself, and there is no language support for the equivalent to a C++ copy constructor.

Therefore, when creating the `books_2` list based on `books_1`, while it does make a copy of the internal collection in `books_1`, *only the references are copied.* Each item in `books_2` **initially** refers to the *same object* as the equivalent item in `books_1`.

I say "initially", because you can of course add and remove entire items from the `books_2` list without effecting `books_1`. In this way, you do have a copy of the initial list; the `books_2` list is its own object, and not just a reference to the same list as `books_1`. But since the list is for a reference type you only have copies of the references, and underlying objects are shared.

Therefore, in the original code, if you want to change the items for `books_2[0]` and `books_2[1]`, you could do it like this:

```
books_2[0] = new Book("Five"); 
books_2[1] = new Book("Six");
```

This would leave `books_1` completely unchanged. However, the `[2]` and `[3]` indexes would still share the same objects between the two lists.

If you really wanted to fully deep copy the entire list, you might do this:

```
var books_2 = books_1.Select(b => new Book(b.title)).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, I get it now. Also, the alternative method for updating the new collection is very useful to know.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly note that `Book` is a reference type, so references to instances of that type are stored in `books_1` and `books_2`.

When you copy the contents of `books_1` to `books_2` you have copied the *references* to the `Book` objects, not the *contents* of the objects themselves.

So after the copy, the situation is as follows for the first element of each list:

```
books_1[0]----\
               \ 
             {Book0}   
               /
books_2[0]----/
```

Now you should be able to see that when you change `books_1[0].title` you will be changing `Book0.title` - and because that same object is referenced by `books_2[0]` then it will change it for that reference too - because it's referencing the same object.

If you think of the references as more like C++ pointers, you should get it.

Comment: You can absolutely think of C# references as C++ references; except that you cannot store them in arrays, for whatever reason. (Obviously, the C and C++ type systems are broken -- a variable should not have the same type as a literal, something Algol68 got right: `5` is an int, `i` is a ref int.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that makes sense. I didn't know objects are reference types.

Comment: @TomiTsolov To be clear: In C# you can have reference types (classes) and value types (structs).